# Why 2 different Module can access each other when added as depend to third module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, mean

I am having 3 **modules** in my **AngularJS** App, e.g. `main`, `home` and `product`. `main` module having `home` and `product` module as dependencies (`ng.module('main', ['home', 'product'])`) while `home` and `product` modules are not having any dependencies(`ng.module('product', [])` `ng.module('phome', [])`), still `product` module can access `home` module service? WHY???

Below is sample code of my application, which is having the same scenario and same issue. And this is [JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitThakkar01/do9966k4/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">
<body ng-controller="MainController as mainController">
{{mainController.name}}
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function (ng) {
    var homeModule = ng.module('home', []);
    homeModule.service("HomeService", [function () {
        var homeService = this;
        homeService.getName = function () {
            return "Home Service";
        }
    }]);
    var productModule = ng.module('product', []);
    productModule.service("ProductService", ["HomeService", function (HomeService) {
        var productService = this;
        productService.getName = function () {
            return "Product Service - " + HomeService.getName();
        };
    }]);
    var mainModule = ng.module('main', ['home', 'product']);
    mainModule.controller("MainController", ['ProductService', function (ProductService) {
        var mainController = this;
        mainController.name = ProductService.getName();
    }]);
})(angular);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is because home service gets defined as a global variable which can be accessed from anywhere within the app. Try reading http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. Angular doesn't scope the contents of a module to the module itself. I've read somewhere that there have been discussions of adding this functionality, but I haven't yet seen it implemented.

To make matters worse, controllers applied to one imported module will be unique within your app. As an example, I was once using angular-ui bootstrap and someone on my team added an `AlertController`. We were pretty confused when the controller was never hit, but it was because angular-ui had already defined the controller.

So it's not just a question of visibility, but also of maintainability and naming.

Everything defined on a module is public.

Comment: This is so so terrible. Lucky after 1.5 years of angular'ing, I've yet to run into this issue.

Comment: I seem to recall the `NameCtrl` standard coming from this issue, to avoid clashing with `NameController` from 3rd party libraries. It has actually hit my team three or four times until we stated following the `NameCtrl` convention.

Answer (score 0):

It works because the dependency of `home` module is added to the `main` module and as `main` is only calling the `product service` therefore it should be only dependent on `product` module.

If you remove the `home` module dependency form the `main` module (which should be the case) it stops working.

**TLDR**; The down side of not adding the `home` dependency to `product` module is that it would not working by only adding the product dependency but you have to add the `home` dependency as well to work with `product service`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grm8y489/)